# INSERT OPENQUERY timeout

Tags: t-sql, hive, linked-server

I'm trying to execute and insert query to a linked server in SQL Server.

For that I'm using `INSERT INTO OPENQUERY` statement.

The linked server is an Apache HIVE using Cloudera ODBC Provider.

The insert operation takes around 1 minute in my setup when performed from HIVE client.

However, SQL INSERT always times out after 30 seconds.

I set the Query Timeout parameter to 0 but it seems to be not affecting INSERT statement, however, it is working fine for SELECT statements taking longer time.

Is this a known limitation?
Is there a way to change the timeout for the insert statement when using `OPENQUERY`?

**EDIT**

I would like to clarify the setup I'm working with.

```
----------                     ----------------------    ---------------
| MS SQL | => Linked Server => | Hive ODBC Provider | => | Hive Server |
----------                     ----------------------    ---------------
```

In Hive, I have a table called calc_result where I would like to periodically store calculation results from the SQL server. For example, I try to insert using a query like this.

```
insert openquery(HIVE, 'select timestamp timestamp , tag tag, value value from calc_result')
values('2019-04-22 11:50:41', 'test',2.0)
```

The insert operation is captured correctly by HIVE server and a MapReduce job starts. However, the job will be killed after 30 seconds due to timeout.

The SQL server will show the below error message.

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "HIVE" returned message "[Cloudera][Hardy] (72) Query execution timeout expired.".

However, `SELECT OPENQUERY` works fine and would follow **Query Timeout** settings of the linked server (Which is set to 0 in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't find a way to change `OPENQUERY`timeout from 30 seconds, I found that using `EXEC AT` Linked Server to work fine for INSERT queries while adhering to timeout settings.

I accidentally stumbled upon the solution [in this 2009 blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/). Databases might not be my strength, but I feel SQL Server documentation can be improved. A simple page that lists possible ways to interact with a Linked Server could've saved me lots of retries.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** that is completely different use case from what I've imagined.  In that case there should not be any difference in select/insert.

As you have configured your linked server timeout, there is a second place in the linked server properties you can check a **Command Timeout** setting in the provider string:

[image]

Other option that comes into my mind is instance wide timout.  Default set for 600 seconds (10 minutes) which is way above your 30 seconds.  However, you can still try it to see if there is any impact.

For infinite wait:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
go
reconfigure
go
sp_configure 'remote query timeout (s)',0
go
reconfigure
go
```

Comment: I tried using sp_who2 but coulding find any BLK processes.  I will clarify the layout in my question for better understanding.

Comment: @MohamedAli I understood your question in completely different fasion, see my edit

Comment: I have tried both settings without success. The CommandTimeout parameters work if I use the ODBC driver programmatically in C# code. However, from SQL Server it seems like the 30 seconds timeout for INSERT is unchangeable.

Comment: @MohamedAli That is weird. What is your provider string now?  Are you using multiple linked servers?  Is the SQL server on the same server as HIVE ODBC (and/or HIVE server)?

Comment: I set the provider string to 'Command Timeout=600'. I don't have multiple linked servers, I'm executing the query from the SQL server using SSMS. The ODBC driver is on the same server as SQL SERVER while HIVE server runs in Cloudera Virtual Machine.

Comment: @MohamedAli I see. How far is the Cloudera Virtual Machine from the SQL Server\ODBC (traceroute hops and response time)?  Does the same happen if you wrap it in a TSQL procedure and run it from there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193301/discussion-between-mohamed-ali-and-tukan).

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `SELECT INTO` temporary table and then materializing it using regular `INSERT INTO`:

```
SELECT c1, c2
INTO #temp_tab
FROM OPENQUERY(mylinkedserver, 'SELECT c1, c2 FROM remote_table');

INSERT INTO normal_table(col1, col2)
SELECT c1, c2
FROM #temp_tab;
```

EDIT:

You could try wrapping it with transaction and remove aliases:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
insert openquery(HIVE, 'select timestamp, tag, value from calc_result')
values('2019-04-22 11:50:41', 'test',2.0);
COMMIT;
```

If necessary set up DTC: [How can I enable distributed transactions for a linked server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60858/how-can-i-enable-distributed-transactions-for-a-linked-server)

Comment: Hi, SELECT FROM OPENQUERY works fine for me, sql server will wait for the qery to finish. My issue is when I try to INSERT to the linked server using INSERT OPENQUERY statement. I will try to clarify the question to reflect my setup.

Comment: @MohamedAli Hmmm, could you try to open and commit transaction explicitly?

Comment: HIVE ODBC does not support transactions unfortunately.